# I have a table with a set of data and I would want to display specific records from it using Mysql:

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r, bigdata

Here is the table: Sorry couldn't depict the table properly here.

```
Id  Date1   Rank1   date2     Rank2

100 1/1/01  1      1/2/01        1

100 1/2/01  1      1/3/01        1

100 1/3/01  1      1/5/01        4
```

Now, I would want to see the result where the rank changes but the date1 should display the date from which Rank = 1 started,
An output like this:

```
Id    Date1    Rank1      date2    Rank2

100   1/1/01      1     1/5/01        4
```

Can anyone please let me know how to go about doing this in MYSQL? I thought about using SQL cursor.Is there another way?

Comment: Please limit questions to a single database engine, unless you want a comparison.  It is very likely that the answer for one will not apply to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will create a stored procedure and a cursor to iterate through each record.

My stored procedure will look as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetChangedRank`()
BEGIN

# Variables containing the final result
DECLARE ID INTEGER;
DECLARE DATE1 DATE;
DECLARE Rank1 INTEGER;
DECLARE DATE2 DATE;
DECLARE Rank2 INTEGER;

DECLARE ROWNUM INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

# Temporary variables to store values of each row.
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ID_VALUE INT;
DECLARE DATE1_VALUE DATE;
DECLARE Rank1_VALUE INT;
DECLARE DATE2_VALUE DATE;
DECLARE Rank2_VALUE INT;

# testtable is the table that contains data

DECLARE RECORDS_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM testtable;

# To check if we reached the end of the result set
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER  FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 # Open cursor
OPEN RECORDS_CURSOR;

# Loop to fetch one row at a time
get_records: LOOP
# Fetch row values to different variables
FETCH RECORDS_CURSOR INTO ID_VALUE, DATE1_VALUE, Rank1_VALUE, DATE2_VALUE, Rank2_VALUE 
# To track the row number
SET ROWNUM = ROWNUM + 1;

# Quit the loop when the end of resultset is reached.
IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_records;
 END IF;

# Assign the first row values to the final values. Date2 and Rank2 will be updated when the rank is changed.
IF ROWNUM = 1 THEN
    BEGIN       
        SET ID = ID_VALUE;
        SET DATE1 = DATE1_VALUE;
        SET Rank1 = Rank1_VALUE;
        SET DATE2 = DATE2_VALUE;    
        SET Rank2 = Rank2_VALUE;    
    END;
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        # Date2 and Rank2 is updated with the row values as the rank is changed.
        IF Rank1_VALUE != Rank2_VALUE THEN
            BEGIN
                SET DATE2 =DATE2_VALUE;
                SET Rank2 = Rank2_VALUE;
            END;    
            END IF;
    END;    
END IF;

END LOOP  get_records;

# Select the final values
SELECT ID, DATE1, Rank1, DATE2, Rank2;

# Close cursor
CLOSE RECORDS_CURSOR;

END
```

Once the procedure is created, you can run this procedure as follow

```
CALL GetChangedRank;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM <table name>
WHERE Rank1 <> Rank2
```

Comment: It doesn't give the "1/1/01" ,i.e the minimum date for the rank 1. The output for this would be this: 100 1/3/01  1      1/5/01        4.  It would just return the last row.

Comment: You say you want "only the records where the rank changes". Seems like you want something else too. Please explain fully. Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately I would want to see the result where the rank changes but the date1 should display the date from which Rank = 1 started. Please refer to the output I have mentioned. It would help me to find the duration in which the "ID" was in ranking 1 before changing to 4, Thanks.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this nested query

`Select Id, (select Date1 from TableName group by Rank1) as Date1, Rank1, Date2, Rank2 from TableName where Rank1<>Rank2;`

Comment: It works well,  but could not apply for the entire dataset.. had to use some joins, thanks :)